# How to import CSV file utf-8 with Spanish characters (á, é, í, ó, ú, ñ) into a table in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, excel

I set the database collation utf8_unicode_ci, the same with the table where I want to import datas from CSV file, and the same with the columns, but It keep showing me the character: ?

Although appear this message. The returned character is always '?'
 Import has been successfully finished, 1 query executed. (prueba.csv)
 MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0376 seconds.)

Comment: Why would you even use PHPMyAdmin ? Check this : https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: A) Make sure your input data is actually UTF-8. B) Make sure you're using *UTF-8 all the way through*, as there are many settings which must be aligned.